# How do I uninstall Ubuntu's Unity login screen or fix its mistaken idea of my password?

Tags: linux, passwords, login-screen, ubuntu-unity, enlightenment

New install of full Ubuntu Server. Then manually added minimal install of Unity desktop. It was painfully slow, so I uninstalled it (using remove and purge options) and installed Enlightenment.

But the login screen still looks like before (incl same wallpaper). But worse, it no longer recognizes my password! Only ever had one user (me) and I never changed my password.

Possible reasons for mishap?? Unity was running in a session in a TeamViewer window while I uninstalled it in a session running in an SSH terminal window. Both logged in under the same user.

I tried resetting the password to the same password and system claimed I had not changed the password, proving my recollection of password was correct.

I have a near verbatim log of each command I issued if it would help.

Comment: If it's a new install, the quickest thing to do will be to simply do a new install. BUT: You'll need to format the partitions to make it a fresh install. Basically, what you did previously was the equivalent of a repair install.

Comment: I don't think I did a repair install. Full install with partition formatting then install of Ubuntu Desktop from within booted instance of the first install. That is just a package install.